# GORM update query automatically assign time column in where condition

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm new to golang my struct is like below

```
type User struct{
    ID int `gorm:"column:ID;primary_key:auto_increment" json:"ID"`
    Name *string `gorm:"column:Name;default:null" json:"Name"`
    DeletedAt *time.Time `gorm:"column:DeletedAt;default:null" json:"DeletedAt"`
}
```

My update query like below in go

```
if err := database.GetMysqlDB().Debug().Model(&User{}).Where("ID = ?", 15).UpdateColumns(user).Error; err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

But my Mysql debug like below

```
UPDATE User SET <data> WHERE DelatedAt IS NULL and ID = 15
```

I don't understand why the query adds the DeletedAt column in the where condition?

**Note**
My table name and columns are in uppercase

Comment: It's because of the soft-delete option that is enabled when `DeleteAt` column is available in the table.
https://gorm.io/docs/delete.html#Soft-Delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per information from [this](https://gorm.io/docs/delete.html#Soft-Delete) link, when `DeleteAt *time.Time` is added to any struct, the soft-delete feature will be enabled for the matching database table. That is why all of your queries with the `User` model will include the `WHERE DeletedAt IS NULL` condition.

To go around this, you can use `Unscoped` method, which will include the soft-deleted records in your SQL queries.

```
if err := database.GetMysqlDB().Debug().Unscoped().Model(&User{}).Where("ID = ?", 15).UpdateColumns(user).Error; err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```